# Can we write $\int_p^\infty\int_q^\infty f(x,y)dxdy=\int_p^\infty\int_q^\infty\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F(x,y)=F(\infty,\infty)-F(p,q)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Let $(X,Y)$ be non-negative absolutely continuous random vector with density function $f(x,y)$ and distribution function $F(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F(x,y)=f(x,y).$

Can we write $\int_p^\infty\int_q^\infty f(x,y)dxdy=\int_p^\infty\int_q^\infty\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F(x,y)=F(\infty,\infty)-F(p,q)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
     \int_p^\infty \int_q^\infty f(x, y)dx dy = \mathbb{P}(X \ge q, Y \ge p) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \le q \text{ or } Y \le p)\\\\ = 1 - \mathbb{P}(X \le q) - \mathbb{P}(Y \le p) + \mathbb{P}(X \le q, Y \le p)
$$
So:
$$
   \int_p^\infty \int_q^\infty f(x, y)dx dy = F(\infty, \infty) - F(q, \infty) - F(\infty, p) + F(q, p)
$$
where
$$
     F(x, y) = \mathbb{P}(X \le x, Y \le y)
$$